# Ruby, random failures with File.new

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I have a script that works great, except that it randomly fails generating new files...

this is the code:

```
...
file_log_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'log', "xls_import_#{Time.now.to_i}.log")
@log = File.new(file_log_path, 'w+')
....
```

and this is the error inside delayed_job.log

```
2012-12-21T18:18:41+0100: [Worker(delayed_job host:webserver2.netbanana.it pid:24482)] LoadDataFromCsv failed with Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /var/www/rails/myapp/releases/20121210093945/log/xls_import_1356110321.log - 0 failed attempts
2012-12-21T18:18:41+0100: [Worker(delayed_job host:webserver2.netbanana.it pid:24482)] PERMANENTLY removing LoadDataFromCsv because of 1 consecutive failures.
```

Other times, it works! Someone can help me?

-- edit:

Well... it seems that Rails.root uses a wrong deploy path...  in fact /var/www/rails/myapp/releases/20121210093945 doesn't exists.

But, as I said, the script sometimes works, sometimes not... If I reload delayed_job, my script works a few, and then start failing.

Comment: Are you sure that path exists after you deploy your app? You might be missing the `log` directory.

Comment: Well... it seems that delayed_job uses a wrong deploy path...  /var/www/rails/myapp/releases/20121210093945 doesn't exists. But, as I said, the script sometimes works, sometimes not... If I reload delayed_job, my script works a few, and then start failing.

Comment: @MichDart Well, obviously, sometimes it does not.

Comment: I modified my comment above.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't some sort of race condition? Do you have a different process reading and writing or creating these logs? What about `Time.now.to_i` using a 1 second resolution. Are you doing something more often than once per second?

Comment: You gave me a bad sensation... :) I found several delayed_job processes (zombies), running on my application... killed them all (not metallica's song)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several delayed_job processes (zombies), still running... killed them all (not metallica's song) and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Capistrano to manage your releases, which I'm guessing is the case based on the path structure, then you'll need to be careful about referencing paths which can be removed after a deployment has occurred. DelayedJob needs to be restarted each time you deploy or it might be working in an orphaned directory.

If possible, you might want to use the `shared/log` path instead since that persists between deployments.

Comment: I'm using Capistrano and I'm aware of restarting delayed_job after each deployment. The use of shared/log is a great idea that might solve my issue... but I'd like to understand why this happens.

Comment: I'm using Capistrano and I'm aware of restarting delayed_job after each deployment. I already use shared/log

Comment: You could add some debugging code in there to complain about what is or isn't there, or even save the result of a `Dir.entries` list. Something odd is going on if your deployment directory disappears.

Comment: I found several delayed_job processes (zombies), still running... killed them all (not metallica's song) and now it works!